# Fitting a multiline suptitle (not enough vertical space)

Tags: matplotlib

How do I create enough vertical space to contain a figure's title when using subplots?

See the code (and output) below,

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt 
import numpy as np

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(9, 3))
fig.suptitle("Figure 1: Some test title \n With a Second line \n And a Third line")

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121, title="Model 1")
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)
ax1.plot(x,y)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, title="Model 2")
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.cos(x ** 2)
ax2.plot(x,y)

fig.tight_layout()
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Use constrained_layout instead of tight_layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the `y` argument in `fig.suptitle()`:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt 
import numpy as np

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(9, 3))
fig.suptitle("Figure 1: Some test title \n With a Second line \n And a Third line", y=1.2)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121, title="Model 1")
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)
ax1.plot(x,y)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, title="Model 2")
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.cos(x ** 2)
ax2.plot(x,y)

fig.tight_layout()
fig.show()
```

[image]